# Selecting default values in multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Problem with multiselect: I am having a need of selecting default options in a multiselect dropdown. Here I am working with Struts2 and default options are coming from server.

**Struts Code:**

```
<select multiple >
    <s:iterator var="user" value="%{USERS}"> 
        <option  <s:if test="%{#approvalStep.isUserSelected(#user.userId) == true}"> selected="selected" </s:if> value="<s:property value="#user.userId"/>" > <s:property value="#user.userName"/></option>
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

**Result of Struts Code:**

```
<div id="selectAndRemoveUser">
    <select multiple="">
        <option selected="selected" value="2000000002007"> aftabalamm7861111111</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2000000003015"> aftabalam.m+12</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2000000003011"> Aftab</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2000000026353"> aftabalam.m+approver1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Problem:**
    When I am trying to get the selected option using Jquery It's only returning the first option. And if I manually edit the select > option  elements (I mean re-write the selected=selected using browser inspect element) it's work fine.

Jquery Code:

```
console.log($("#selectAndRemoveUser").find('select :selected').length); // the result is 1;

if($("#selectAndRemoveUser").find('select :selected').length > 1 ) {
    alert('false');
} else {
    alert('true');
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xaLxkhzx/2/ Your code is working

Comment: Make sure you have wraped your js code in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

```
For multiselect dropdown, the name of the select field should be defined as array i.e add 'name[]' at the end of the name attribute.

**HTML** : 
<div id="selectAndRemoveUser">
    <select multiple="" name = "user[]">
        <option value="2000000002007"> aftabalamm7861111111</option>
        <option value="2000000003015"> aftabalam.m+12</option>
        <option value="2000000003011"> Aftab</option>
        <option value="2000000026353"> aftabalam.m+approver1</option>
    </select>
</div>

**Jquery** :

$("select")
  .change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    console.log(str);
  })
  .trigger("change");
```